# "SDL2.DLL missing from computer" but is in the same folder as program?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdl

SDL Folder in the same directory:
[image]

Contents of SDL folder:
[image]

I cant get my program to run as it says it cannot find SDL2.DLL? Any ideas?

Comment: `SDL2.DLL` needs to be in the same directory as your program; or the directory containing it needs to be on your `PATH`.

Comment: As Richard says, put it in the same folder as the `.exe` file

Comment: In the future, please don't link to stuff. Put all relevant info *in the question* as plain text. Bad question; no upvote for you.

Comment: Thank you so much guys, that solved the problem, I placed the relevant DLLs in the debug folder!

Answer (score 3):

Programs don't search your entire hard drive for DLLs.  That would be expensive, horribly insecure, and bug prone.

Instead they have a search path, which depends on how you load it.  Often your `PATH` environment variable is used, together with various other system places, as well as the directory of the process loading the dynamic library.

This list rarely includes "a subdirectory of the process executable called `SDL`".  You can, however, modify the search path; how exactly depends on how you are trying to load SDL.

The easy solution is to try to copy them all into the same directory.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a **Post-Build-Event** to copy `sdl2.dll` into the directory where your `.exe` is built. Manually copying the file is fine for a quick test, but having Visual Studio do it for you has some advantages. For example, this lets you completely delete your `Debug` and `Release` directories and have the correct file copied when you do a clean build.

In your directory listing I see `bin32` and `bin64` directories inside the `SDL` directory. I assume that there is a copy of `sdl2.dll` directly inside each of those directories, but there are no separate debug and release versions, just 32-bit and 64-bit. Let me know if this is incorrect, otherwise, you can do this:

Open the **Solution Explorer** and select your project (not the solution). Then use **Alt+Enter** to go directly to the Property Pages. (Or right-click the project and select **Properties** at the bottom of the menu.)

In the selection panel on the left, go to **Configuration Properties**/**Build Events**/**Post-Build Event**.

At the top of the property sheet, set the **Configuration** dropdown to **All Configurations** and the **Platform** dropdown to **All Platforms**.

Click the edit box to the right of **Command Line** and enter this command:

```
copy "$(SolutionDir)SDL\bin$(PlatformArchitecture)\sdl2.dll" "$(TargetDir)"
```

Now click **OK**, and save and build your solution. You should find that it copies the correct version (32-bit or 64-bit) of `sdl2.dll` into the build directory.

The various `$(FooBar)` entries in the command line are macros which ar automatically expanded according to things like your project directory location, the type of platform you're building for, etc.

`$(SolutionDir)` is the directory containing your `.sln` file, *with a trailing backlash*.

`$(PlatformArchitecture)` is `32` or `64` depending on which platform you're building for.

`$(TargetDir)` is the directory that VS creates your `.exe` file in.

So this command line is an ordinary `copy` command as you might use in a command prompt, with the paths filled in to copy either `SDL\bin32\sdl2.dll` or `SDL\bin64\sdl2.dll` to your build target directory. We use quotes around the source and destination paths in case you have any spaces in your project path.

In some cases you may need specific commands for a particular configuration (Debug/Release) or platform (Win32/x64). You can do this by selecting that configuration or platform at the top of the property sheet. In our case, we can use one command for both 32-bit and 64-bit builds thanks to the `$(PlatformArchitecture)` macro.

To learn more about the macros, you can select the **Command Line** box in the property page and then click the drop-down arrow that appears to the right of the box, and select **<Edit...>**. This opens a multiline edit window (you can use more than one command in the build event), with an **Evaluated value** below it that shows the actual command that will be used for your current configuration and platform. You can inspect this command to see if it looks right, and you can also copy the evaluated command and paste it into a command prompt window for a quick test.

To see a full list of available macros and what they expand to for your current configuration/platform, click the **Macros>>** button below that and look through the list or use the search box at the top.